# how to link Weka with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, weka, pca

I have a  dataset for which I need to process PCA (Principal Component Analysis, A dimentionality reduction program) which is easy to proceed using Weka.

And Since the dataset is large in size, Weka shows memory issues, which can be resolved if I link Weka with Hadoop. To run the algorithm using weka in a server. Could anyone help me regarding the same. How can I connect Weka with Hadoop to deal with larger dataset? Please help!

Thankyou..

Comment: Does this help? http://markahall.blogspot.in/2013/10/weka-and-hadoop-part-1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weka 3.7 has new packages for distributed processing in Hadoop. One of the jobs provided by these packages will compute a correlation (or covariance) matrix in Hadoop. The user can optionally have the job use the correlation matrix as input to a PCA analysis (this part runs outside of Hadoop) and produce a "trained" Weka PCA filter. This scales Weka's PCA analysis in the number of instances (but not in the number of original features since the PCA computation still happens locally on the client machine).

For more info on the Hadoop packages see:

http://markahall.blogspot.co.nz/2013/10/weka-and-hadoop-part-1.html

The distributedWekaHadoop package can be installed via the package manager in Weka 3.7.

Cheers,
Mark.

Comment: Can the Weka package work with Hadoop 2.5.x and above? I've tried running it on Hadoop 2.6.0 but it gave version mismatched. Based on the documentation by Mark Hall, the package was run on Hadoop 1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the algorithm, it may be quite complex to rewrite it to use Hadoop.

You can use [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) instead. [It does have support for PCA](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Principal+Components+Analysis).